# spring mvc 3.1 catches jackson.map.jsonmappingexception and re-throws HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

looks like in 3.0.5, spring will not catch the jsonmappingexception and will just throw it.
Is it a bug fix or what? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/commits/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java